# How to automatically save data from API - Ruby on Rails

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have searched all over the internet, however, I cannot seem to get a clear answer on this issue. I am using Block.io API to add Bitcoin payments to my app. I receive a JSON hash which includes a new Bitcoin address for each payment, I can extract the bitcoin address, but I need it to save to my database automatically, when a user accesses a specific page the address will also be generated on that page. I am using Postgresql

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST", "address"=>"2MstFNxtnp3pLLuXUK4Gra5dMcaz132d4dt", "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

I have a controller which calls the API to generate the address:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
  end
end
```

And the bitcoin address is displayed using:

```
<%= @new_address["data"]["address"] %>
```

I am thinking of creating a new function that will save the bitcoin address to the database and map the route to execute this function upon accessing the specific page, something like:

Controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address

 ## I need assistance with the rest to auto save

  end
end
```

routes:

```
match '/save_btc' => 'payments#create', via: [:get, :post]
```

when someone opens domain.com/save_btc the bitcoin address needs to be automatically saved to the database.

I have already generated the following migration

```
rails g model Payment bitcoin:string
```

Any comments or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, don't use GET requests for anything that modifies state, saves something new etc. It's not semantic and it's problematic in terms of security regarding CSRF, logs etc. Use POST/PUT/PATCH instead. After that, just try to do it e.g. with a regular `create` controller action and see what happens. You can come back anytime if you experience a specific problem.

Comment: I'm with @HalilÖzgür here. Do try and use standard REST endpoints unless you have a truly exceptional case. This could be better routed through something like `bitcoin_addresses#create` via POST.

Comment: @tadman I have updated the controller and routing, but I am unfamiliar with saving data from a 3rd party API, can you offer some guidance on the proper syntax to call the API BlockIo.get_new_address and also save it. As I am accustomed to using the model/controller as payment = Payment.new etc... How or were is the API "plugged in" on this method?

Comment: Normally you create a method that does something like `BitcoinAddress.create(address: BlockIo.get_new_addres['data']['address'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `BlockIo` is already parsing the JSON string for you and returning a regular Ruby hash.

I would try something like this:

```
new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
Payment.create( bitcoin: new_address['data']['address'] )
```

You'll probably want to check the status of the response `new_address['status']` and make sure that the address is present before saving.  But the code above should get you started.

You'll probably want to do a redirect or something like `head :ok` after the payment is created.

Note: you do not need to use the `@` for the variable name.  That is usually only used when you're passing that info to a view.